# Построение тора

Tags: c++, opengl

Помогите разобраться с кодом. Что в нем происходит?
`phi = 0.0;` для чего нужно?
И что делает `glNormal3f`? Можно ли без нее?

```
void Kolco(GLfloat r, GLfloat R, GLint nsides, GLint rings)

    //cosTheta  1/2 of sin(2 theta)
 //theta угол поворота
 int i, j;                         //
  GLfloat theta, phi, theta1;      //
  GLfloat cosTheta, sinTheta;      // Объявление переменных
  GLfloat cosTheta1, sinTheta1;    //
  GLfloat ringDelta, sideDelta;    //

  ringDelta = 2.0 * M_PI / rings;//уравнение окружности верх
  sideDelta = 2.0 * M_PI / nsides;//уровнение окружности Бок

  theta = 0.0;  //
  cosTheta = 1.0;//угол поворота для соединения квадратов в кольцо
  sinTheta = 0.0;//
  for (i = rings - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    theta1 = theta + ringDelta;//
    cosTheta1 = cos(theta1);//   верхнее кольцо
    sinTheta1 = sin(theta1);//
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);//
    phi = 0.0;
    for (j = nsides; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
      GLfloat cosPhi, sinPhi, dist;//
      phi += sideDelta;//
      cosPhi = cos(phi);// боковые
      sinPhi = sin(phi);//
      dist = R + r * cosPhi;//

    glNormal3f(cosTheta1 * cosPhi, -sinTheta1 * cosPhi, sinPhi);
       glVertex3f(cosTheta1 * dist, -sinTheta1 * dist, r * sinPhi);
   glNormal3f(cosTheta * cosPhi, -sinTheta * cosPhi, sinPhi);
    glVertex3f(cosTheta * dist, -sinTheta * dist,  r * sinPhi);
    }
    glEnd();
    theta = theta1;
    cosTheta = cosTheta1;
    sinTheta = sinTheta1;
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Предположительно, это исходник `glutWireTorus`, соответственно, из `GLUT`, который был кощунственно обозван как `Kolco`.*

Здесь строится тор с внутренним радиусом `r` и внешним `R`. Разъяснение **математической составляющей построения тора** при желании можно найти самостоятельно, более хороший и "внятный" пример построения тора можно найти [**здесь.**](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/MathCG/OpenGLsoft/WrapTorus/WrapTorus.html) *Обратите особое внимание на метод `putVert(i, j)`.*

---

Отмечу, что отдельная *"вкусная"* особенность текущего заключается в том, что для объединения вершин используется подход `GL_QUAD_STRIP` и это один из хороших примеров его применения.